# import clob data in parquet format with scoop

Tags: sql, hdfs, sqoop, parquet, clob

I'm trying to importe clob data with scoop in parquet format here is my command line:

```
sshpass -p ${MDP_MAPR} ssh -n ${USR_MAPR}@${CNX_MAPR} sqoop import -Dmapred.job.queue.name=root.leasing.dev --connect ${CNX_DB} --username ${USR_DB} --password ${MDP_DB} --query "${query}" --delete-target-dir --target-dir ${DST_HDFS}/${SOURCE}_${table} --hive-overwrite --hive-import --hive-table ${SOURCE}_${table} --hive-database ${DST_HIVE} --hive-drop-import-delims  -m 1 ${DRIVER_DB} --as-parquetfile >>${ficTrace} 2>&1
```

but it doesn't work and I can't find why, here is the log I get from it's execution:

```
Warning: /opt/mapr/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.6/bin/../../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
18/07/09 14:44:42 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-mapr-1703
18/07/09 14:44:42 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
18/07/09 14:44:42 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
18/07/09 14:44:42 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/mapr/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/mapr/hive/hive-2.1/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
18/07/09 14:44:43 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
18/07/09 14:44:43 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
18/07/09 14:44:43 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
18/07/09 14:44:44 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
18/07/09 14:44:44 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select * from doe.DE_DECISIONS where  (1 = 0)
18/07/09 14:44:44 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select * from doe.DE_DECISIONS where  (1 = 0)
18/07/09 14:44:44 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0
Note: /tmp/sqoop-mapr/compile/2b49a98afbeb2ac1135adc84c66cf092/QueryResult.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
18/07/09 14:44:48 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-mapr/compile/2b49a98afbeb2ac1135adc84c66cf092/QueryResult.jar
18/07/09 14:44:53 INFO tool.ImportTool: Destination directory /app/list/datum/data/calf_hors_prod-cluster/datum/dev/leasing/tmp_sqoop/DE_DECISIONS is not present, hence not deleting.
18/07/09 14:44:53 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning query import.
18/07/09 14:44:53 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
18/07/09 14:44:53 INFO mapreduce.JobBase: Setting default value for hadoop.job.history.user.location=none
18/07/09 14:44:53 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
18/07/09 14:44:53 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select * from doe.DE_DECISIONS where  (1 = 0)
18/07/09 14:44:53 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select * from doe.DE_DECISIONS where  (1 = 0)
18/07/09 14:44:54 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: Cannot convert SQL type 2005
```

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this at the end of your Sqoop command:

```
--map-column-java <ORACLE_CLOB_COLUMN_NAME>=String
```

For example, if the Oracle table has a column named BODY of type CLOB, add this at the end:

```
--map-column-java BODY=String
```

This will provide guidance to Sqoop on Oracle CLOB type to Java type mapping.

If there are multiple columns, you can use this syntax pattern:

```
--map-column-java <ORACLE_CLOB_COLUMN_NAME_1>=String,<ORACLE_CLOB_COLUMN_NAME_2>=String
```

Comment: hi @Jagrut Sharma, but with theses, the the clob would be stored in binary format wouldn't it ? and I want it to be stored in parquet format . thank you

Comment: The data on HDFS will be in Parquet format. The Hive table will be created with a STRING type for the CLOB column.

Comment: hi @Jagrut Sharma I added :  <code>--map-column-java <ORACLE_CLOB_COLUMN_NAME>=String </code> then it didin't worked got this error in the log :

Comment: i did and it didin't worked : got this error in the log : sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input within/between OBJECT entries
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@28f6137b; line: 1, column: 6001]
org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input within/between OBJECT entries
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@28f6137b; line: 1, column: 6001]
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:955)

Comment: Can you provide some details of the CLOB column - definition and some sample data?

Comment: Sorry I can't, as I'm in an internship program: but I looked over the internet: http://bigdatainourpalm.blogspot.com/2017/05/sqoop-import-failure-to-hive-parquet.html

Comment: It seems that the variable PARAM_VALUE  is too short: VARCHAR(4000) and I'll need to increase its size to 20000 for example, but don't have the priviledge to do it.

Comment: do you happen to know the effects of increasing the size of PARAM_VALUE ?

Comment: The error in that blog seems to be different than what you are getting. TABLE_PARAMS is a Hive metastore table holding details about table parameters (key-value pairs). The Hive table for this import will contain a property with the key `avro.schema.url` containing location for `.avsc` schema file on HDFS. It is unlikely that this location info will exceed the `varchar(4000)` default limit for PARAM_VALUE column. Since sample data is not available, it is a bit tough to reproduce the issue. I could run this for a test table with CLOB column successfully.

Comment: I don't know but maybe this error might happens on any table that contains clob data ?